# get method as text

Tags: delphi, method-names

I need to save and load some properties to a database and I am stuck with this.
I have a form with several methods and a button. button.onclick event is assigned to one of the form's methods.
I need to get the name of the assigned method as string (just like Object inspector "form1.proc1") and save it to the database. Later I need to get the method name from the database and assign button.onclick to the corresponding form's method.
Is this possible at all?

```
Form1 = class(TForm)
...
procedure proc1(Sender: TObject);
procedure proc2(Sender: TObject);
procedure proc3(Sender: TObject);

Button1.OnClick = readMethodNameFromDatabase; 
...
saveMethodToDatabase(Button1.OnClick);
```

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve that would require saving the name of the methods to a database? You can probably use RTTI to do this but I'm trying to understand the reason behind it.

Answer (score 4):

You can obtain a method, given its name, like this:

```
function TForm1.MethodFromName(const Name: string): TNotifyEvent;
begin
  TMethod(Result).Data := Self;
  TMethod(Result).Code := MethodAddress(Name);
  if TMethod(Result).Code=nil then
    raise Exception.CreateFmt('Count not find method named %s', [Name]);
end;
```

This is the mechanism that the RTL uses when reading your .dfm files. It relies on the method being published.

You can call it like this:

```
Button1.OnClick := TNotifyEvent(MethodFromName('Button1Click'));
```

Naturally you'd substitute a database read in the final code.

---

As for the second part of your question, you can get the name of an event handler with this code:

```
MethodName(@Button1.OnClick);
```

Comment: TMethod(Result).Data := Button1; 
  TMethod(Result).Code := MethodAddress('OnClick'); (always returns nil)

Comment: `OnClick` is the name of an event. That's not what you need. You need to pass the name of a method defined in your form. For example, it might be `Button1Click`.

Comment: thanxs for the fast replies, @david. Now I am a bit confused. Using Form1.methodName(Button1.onclick) works only if assigned function (Form1.button1Click) is of the same form. If OnClick is assigned to Form2.DoStuff, I have to call Form2.methodname(...), but how can I know that?? Anyway, it works for me.

Comment: Well, you can do it like this. Use `TObject(TMethod(@Button1.OnClick).Data)` to get hold of the object which implements the method. And then call `MethodName` on that object.